# How to check if a string is a substring of another string

Tags: string-manipulation

I was wondering what is the proper way to test whether a substring is included in some other string. If I want to check if string `a` is part of string `b`, I'm currently using

```
matchstr(b, a) != ""
```

to check if a is a substring of b. Is there a more "proper" way of doing it, since this seems like a bit of a hack.

Comment: You can not use `matchstr` like this, 2nd arg of `matchstr` is a regex pattern, eg: `matchstr('ab', '.')` will return `'a'`.

Comment: @dedowsdi valid comment. This might be relevant to other users, but in my case these strings are guaranteed to not contain regex.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For this there is the function `stridx()`.

```
let a = "Vi and Vim"
let b = "and"
echo stridx(a, b)
" echos 3
```

If the substring is not found `stridx()` returns `-1`. 
The function also supports a third argument to specify the start index to search from.

See `:help stridx()`.

Comment: If you want to accept a match anywhere in the string, including the start of the string, then use `if stridx(a, b) >= 0`

Answer (score 6):

There's an even easier way in at least version 8.x which I've been using for some time:

`if hostname()  =~ '10.12.12.132'`

which is a simple regex match expression with ignorecase. Here's the section from the Vim manual that explains comparisons, which includes this operator.

```
expr5 {cmp} expr5

Compare two expr5 expressions, resulting in a 0 if it evaluates to false, or 1
if it evaluates to true.

                 use 'ignorecase'    match case    ignore case ~
regexp matches           =~             =~#             =~?
regexp doesn't match    !~              !~#             !~?
```

And as pointed out by  [Big McLargeHuge](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/16613/big-mclargehuge) in the comment, the specific form in this case is

```
<string-to-test> =~ <regex-pattern>
```

Comment: To clarify, the pattern goes on the RHS. So if you want to test if string a is part of string b, you'd use `b =~ a`.